# After adding the Logger Provider the Angular Quickstart stopped loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging

Following recommendations from the installed module angular2-logger I am trying to add Logger to QuickStart

By this recommendation after running

```
npm install --save angular2-logger
```

and modification of systemjs.config.js one needs to modify app.module.ts, first  add

```
import { Logger } from "angular2-logger/core";
```

and then add

```
 providers:    [ Logger ] // AND THIS
```

The latter operation results in not loading **Hello Angular**
after starting the server.  So, I see on the screen only

Loading AppComponent content here ...

The new full app.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { Logger } from "angular2-logger/core"; // ADD THIS

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent ],
 bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
 providers:    [ Logger ] // AND THIS
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The console error in the browser is as follows:

```
 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-logger/core
 patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:26
 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:21
 Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:28
 ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:28

 Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-logger/core as "angular2-logger/core" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
 Stack trace:
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-logger/core
patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:26
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:21
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:28

Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-logger/core as "angular2-logger/core" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

Comment: what do you mean by *Angular Quickstart stopped loading*? Any error in console?

Comment: So, I see on the screen only Loading AppComponent content here ....  Changed the problem text also.  I do not see any new console errors.